# Question about linq2sql

Tags: c#, t-sql, linq-to-sql

I have some legacy code with linq2sql classes. DataContext class has following definition for stored procedure:

```
 [Function(Name="dbo.sp_Goods_SelectBySection")]
        public ISingleResult<sp_Goods_SelectBySectionResult> sp_Goods_SelectBySection([Parameter(Name="SectionId", DbType="Int")] System.Nullable<int> sectionId)
        {
            IExecuteResult result = this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())), sectionId);
            return ((ISingleResult<sp_Goods_SelectBySectionResult>)(result.ReturnValue));
        }
```

But when i am trying create same procedure in my own project, designer creating procedure with different implementation:

```
[Function(Name="dbo.sp_Goods_SelectBySection")]
        public int sp_Goods_SelectBySection([Parameter(Name="SectionId", DbType="Int")] System.Nullable<int> sectionId)
        {
            IExecuteResult result = this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())), sectionId);
            return ((int)(result.ReturnValue));
        }
```

And i cannt change type in method properties.

Here is code of stored procedure.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Goods_SelectBySection]
(
    @SectionId INT
)
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT 
        Goods.Id,
        Goods.[Name],
        TypeId,
        Makerid,
        Price,
        [Description],
        Term,
        Types.Name AS TypeName,
        Makers.Name AS MakerName,
        GoodsImage.SmallImageUrl AS MainImageUrl,
        Goods.IsDeleted,
        Goods.Rang
    FROM Goods 
         INNER JOIN Types ON (Types.Id = Goods.TypeId)
         INNER JOIN Makers ON (Makers.Id = Goods.MakerId)
         LEFT JOIN GoodsImage ON ( GoodsImage.GoodId = Goods.Id AND GoodsImage.IsMain = 1 AND GoodsImage.IsDeleted = 0 )
    WHERE 
        Types.SectionId = @SectionId
        AND Goods.IsDeleted  = 0
    ORDER BY Rang ASC       
END
```

Why? And how i can create procedure which returning ISingleResult instead of int?

Note i have many such procedures and modify by hand each of them is not good idea i think.

---

I guess it's designer problem. Because i created new test project and it work ok. Thanks to all who helped me. Especially to Andras Zoltan.

Comment: Are you sure this is the actual text of the procedure that's compiled in the DB you are pointing the designer at?

Comment: @JohnOpincar Yeah it's actual text of procedure. i am using the same procedure in both case.

Comment: @JohnOpincar - I'm with you on this.  The SP names in the C#/Sql blocks dont match...

Comment: @Neir0 - now that you've updated the code so that all the names match; could you try simply deleting the SP from the L2S designer and dragging it back on again from the server explorer?

Comment: @Andras Zoltan I just copied other procedure to question. Sorry. I edited question.

Comment: @Neir0 - glad to be of help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Sorry, slightly misunderstood your question but I'll keep my initial comments*

Remember that stored procedures return a **result set**, not a value; unless you count the value returned in a `return` statement.  Therefore you need a type to wrap around the columns and rows that are returned.

You can change the return type to a table if you know the SP returns a rowset that maps to one of your table types.  But you are not going to be able to just return 'an int'.

See this link: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/linqprojectgeneral/thread/1667a989-08a0-402c-9358-e4637406a75f (sorry it's over on MSDN forums - not SO :$) and the linked topic from that http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386975.aspx

### Update

L2S uses the equivalent of SQL reflection to figure what an SP returns in order to auto-generate the result.

If the SP doesn't `SELECT`, or if it only has a `RETURN` in it, you will get a basic `int` return type for your mapped function.  This kind of thing can happen legitimately or erroneously if the SP uses `IF` statements to fork and return different results accordingly; L2S cannot possibly figure out a single return type that can satisfy all possible outcomes, and so it just plumps for one of them.

As @JohnOpincar mentions in his comments, there is a question mark over whether the SP you've posted here is actually the one you've mapped - since the names are not the same?  My guess is that you've dragged on the wrong SP - and that's only got a `RETURN` in it, or it returns multiple things and L2S has borked.

### Update 2

Okay - so you've changed the names in the source.  My recommendation is to delete the SP from the L2S designer (and any other manual attempt you may have for this SP), and drag it back on again from the Server Explorer, making sure it's the same server/db you drag it from.  With the SQL you've posted, L2S will most definitely be able to figure out what the result set is as it's very simple.

Comment: Ok. But how i can do it in designer? I donnt want change returning value from ISingleResult to int. I want change from int to ISingleResult.

Comment: @Neir0 Okay - well Linq to Sql examines meta data about the SP to generate the correct return type. If it sees the SP body doesn't `SELECT` but just `RETURNS` it will return an `int`. In which case I would echo what @JohnOpincar said: clarify *for sure* that the SP it looked at has the body you think it does (because the sp you posted doesn't have the same name as the one you mapped in the C#!)

Comment: @Andras Zoltan It's my mistake. I copied other procedure to question. But in my project it is ok. I am using some part of code from legacy project. Everywhere legacy code use procedure with ISingleResult but my procedure returning INT. And as you can see it's not problem with IF statement.

Comment: @Andras Zoltan Follow to you suggestion i deleted stored procedure from designer and then add again. And i have the same problem. Procedure return int. What can i do to detect source of problem?